# How to select a date using regex

Tags: php, regex

in the sentence :

```
 Effectuées le    : 06/09/2013 15:12:30
```

Could you help me please to select only 06/09/2013?
Thank you

edit: I'm using dftotext php function to extract some files and I should match the date that is always written in thios way
(regex+php)

edit2: I have tried :

```
(?<=es le    :)(.*)
```

But it takes all date+ time 
I would select only date 
http://www.rubular.com/r/6qmGKIAn00

Comment: What are the rules around the presence of that date string? Can we expect the string before the colon to always be present, the colon itself (prefaced by three space characters, followed by one), or what?

Comment: but what have you tried?Which language/tool are you using...there may be a better solution other than using regex..

Comment: Have you tried learning regular expressions? This is a very simple task if know how to match a pattern with one or more digits followed by a `/`

Comment: Sorry I'm new with regex :(
I have tried :

(?<=es le    :)(.*)

But it takes all date+ time I would select only date http://www.rubular.com/r/6qmGKIAn00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.*` will match everything after the `:`, including the space and the time. To get just the date, be more specific than a wildcard that matches any character. Use this pattern:

```
#(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})#
```

Capture group #1 will contain the date.

You tagged it as only `regex` and not `php`, but in PHP that would be:

```
preg_match('#(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})#', $string_containing_the_sentence)
```

and the date will be assigned to **$1**.

Comment: Thank you 
I made edit to my 1st post 
Could you help please?
Thank you very much

Comment: I saw the edit. This regex will match only the date, not the time.

Comment: Hello Adi,
Did you mean like this : http://www.rubular.com/r/Il2zqs9h0A

Comment: What will you do if date pattern changes to `yyyy-mm-dd` or if there are more than 1 date per line?

Comment: It will never change ;) I just want to match the date as it's in the format Thank you ;)

Comment: @amorino Well, yes, but the reason it's not working at rubular is that you're being forced to use slashes as the regex delimiters. I used **#** as the delimiter specifically to avoid the need to escape the slashes. Also, since rubular includes the delimiters for you, you should leave them out of the regex: At rubular, try this: `(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})`. In your code, use what's in my answer.

Comment: +1 I agree that this is better than matching anything after a `:`.

Comment: @amorino Okay, but keep in mind that in PHP code, you can avoid the need to escape forward slashes by using something else as the delimiter. # is the usual convention for delimiting a regex that has multiple /'s, though you could use something else if you want (but I think it's better to stick with the conventions, it makes your code more maintainable).

Comment: @anubhava That would be different question. I was trying to answer this one. ;)  Date formats tend to stay consistent within a given data set. And in general, don't you think it's a better approach to write a regex that targets the specs of what you're trying to match rather than what you *don't* want to match? Which one do you think is more likely to have a consistent format that can more reliably be targeted by the regex?

Comment: That depends on source of the data actually.

Comment: @anubhava That's why I said "tend to" rather than "always". But in general terms you're more likely to be able to identify a consistent set of criteria for what you *are* trying to match than surrounding text you don't want to match. Where that's not the case, *that's* when you have a job for zero-width assertions.

Comment: Also, don't forget how much extra load they put on the regex engine, which keeps having to backtrack. For a small job like this it doesn't matter, but I don't think it's a good habit to use zero-width assertions when it's possible to target just what you want to match. Patterns tailored to what you want to match should be considered the bread-and-butter of regex matching, and zero-width assertions should be considered something to pull out of the bag of tricks for special cases, where the match can't be defined without looking at the surrounding text.

Answer (score 1):

This regex should work:

```
le\s*:\s*([^\s]+)
```

#### Live Demo: http://www.rubular.com/r/EZFrNGdWfg

**Alternate regex:**

```
/(\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{2}\d{2}?)/
```

Comment: That'll work in *this* case, but I think it's generally a better idea to write a regex that matches specifically what you want. If you want a regex that matches a /-separtated date, write one tailored to match a /-separated date. Also, lookbehinds are less efficient, they should only be used when necessary.

Comment: The little problem remaining is the spaces between "le" and ":"
http://www.rubular.com/r/y6r6Lu6mOK
It will be nice if I can play with it because it could change in number of spaces

Comment: @AdiInbar: Yes a regex can be written in many ways. It can be tailored to actual requirements. Better not to complicate regex if not needed.

Comment: @amorino: My regex is not matching any space before `:` It just grabs text (date) which follows a `: `

Comment: @amorino That's exactly why I think it's better to use a regex that specifically targets the part you want to match, rather than using a lookbehind to find what you don't want to match and then matching any string of consecutive nonwhitespace characters.

Comment: @anubhava I think you misunderstood. He's not saying that the regex is matching the space. He's saying that it doesn't match the date if the number of spaces after the colon is different. You could change the regex to `?<=: +)[^\s]+` or `?<=:\s+)[^\s]+`, but I still think this is the wrong approach. And a regex that targets the date hardly "complicates" it more than a lookbehind - other way around, and this is a case in point.

Comment: @amorino: You can possibly use this regex: `/(\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{2}\d{2}?)/`

Comment: @AdiInbar: OP wrote: `The little problem remaining is the` **spaces between "le" and ":"** so don't think I misunderstood :)

Comment: instead of `[^\s]+` you can just do `\S+`

Comment: Hello (\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{2}\d{2}?) worked fine with me ;)

Comment: @anubhava Read it again. He specifically said that the little problem with the spacese between "le" and ":" is that the number of spaces can change. Since your original regex wouldn't match at all if the number of spaces is different, it can be inferred that the "little problem" is that it's failing to match, and not that the spaces are included in the match.

Comment: My original regex didn't care about space before `:` so it doesn't matter if if there are 5 spaces between "le" and ":"  or no spaces between "le" and ":" :P

Comment: @anubhava Oh, you're right about that. *I* misread it...I was thinking that the number of spaces between the colon and the date could also vary. But, I still think the regex should be written more to target what you want to match than surrounding text you don't want to match. Zero-width assertions are great, but they should be used when the match is defined by the surrounding text rather than just the content of what's being matched.