# How to match these patterns using regex lookahead?

Tags: regex, perl, regex-lookarounds

I need to put files into separate groups according to a pattern on their filename. What I need is an ID that identifies the group a file belongs to. It does not matter how this id is formed (except it shouldn't be empty), it only needs to be same for all the files in a group. I'm trying to construct the id directly out of the filename according to this rule:

- remove the substring "dokument" or "signatur" from the end of the base file name and a preceding "_" if either string is found
- remove the extension
- precede the result with a dummy string (like "id") to avoid an empty id
- done.

This must be possible with a rather simple regex, but I don't get it to work.

Here's my attempt so far:

```
for (<DATA>) {
my ($match) = ($_ =~ /(.*?)(?:dokument|signatur)?(?:\..*)/);
    print $_ . " => id" . $match . "\n"; 
};

__DATA__
dokument.pdf
dokument.rtf
dokument.html
COO_2026_100_2_dokument.pdf
COO_2026_100_2.zip
dokument.xml
signatur.xml
COO_2026_100_2_dokument.xml
COO_2026_100_2_dokument.rtf
COO_2026_100_2_signatur.xml
COO_2026_100_3_dokument.xml
```

What should happen: 
- `dokument.*` and `signatur.*` go into one group
- `*_2*` go into another group
- `*_3*` goes into a third group

What does happen is that everything is ok except the zip-File, because it has no "_" in its id. I suspect this can be solved by using a look ahead, but I've no clue how. And maybe I'm wrong.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea of a lookahead is to match a given pattern only if it's followed by another pattern (which isn't included in the match). It's hard to follow exactly what you're looking for, but if I understand what you mean, this will work:

```
.*?(?=_?(dokument|signatur|\.[^.]+$))
```

This matches everything up to either `dokument` or `signatur` and the preceding `_` if there is one, or up to the extension of neither of those is present.

A couple of notes:

- You don't have to match the extension *after* `dokument` or `signatur`, you only need to match it if neither of those is found, since if either of them is found, you're only including everything that comes before them (other than a preceding `_`, if any) in the results.
- Matching an extension with `\..*` may work with these filenames, but that's not a reliable way to do it in general, because if there's more than one dot in the filename, it would match everything starting with the first dot. `\.[^.]+$` ensures that you're starting from the last dot.

Also, there's no need to use a match group or assign the results to a variable. Just match the part of the filename you want to use, and retrieve it with **$&**:

```
for (<DATA>) {
    $_ =~ /.*?(?=_?(dokument|signatur|\.[^.]+$))/;
    print $_ . " => id" . $& . "\n";
}
```

Comment: No, as the example data shows, there are files that are simply named "dokument.xml" or "signatur.xml", so no "_" there. I'll try your solution.

Comment: your regex produces different ids than I need. The rule in essence is: remove "dokument" or "signatur" from the filename, and what is left is the id. Except for the _ before dokument|signatur, that has to go as well.

Comment: I'm confused, are you saying that you want to *keep* the extension? The regex in your question implies that you want to exclude it, because it ends with `(?:\..*)`. Otherwise, I don't understand in which way it's not producing the matches you're looking for. Can you include, in the question, exactly what output you want for each of those filenames?

Comment: Oh, I see the problem. You're using the match group in your id rather than the match. Just get rid of **$match** and use **$&**.

Comment: Thanks Adi, now it is working. And now I have to go look up $& :)

Answer (score 0):

It's of course possible to do what you want in a single step.

```
my ($id) = /(.*?)(?:_(?:dokument|signatur))?(?:\.[^.]*)?$/;
```

However, I would recommend breaking your goal into parts to make it easier to debug your intent and isolate bugs:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

for (<DATA>) {
    chomp;

    my $id = $_;
    $id =~ s/\.[^.]*$//;                   # Remove Extension
    $id =~ s/_(?:dokument|signatur)$//;    # Remove Suffix

    print "$_ => id$id\n";
}

__DATA__
dokument.pdf
dokument.rtf
dokument.html
COO_2026_100_2_dokument.pdf
COO_2026_100_2.zip
dokument.xml
signatur.xml
COO_2026_100_2_dokument.xml
COO_2026_100_2_dokument.rtf
COO_2026_100_2_signatur.xml
COO_2026_100_3_dokument.xml
```

Outputs:

```
dokument.pdf => iddokument
dokument.rtf => iddokument
dokument.html => iddokument
COO_2026_100_2_dokument.pdf => idCOO_2026_100_2
COO_2026_100_2.zip => idCOO_2026_100_2
dokument.xml => iddokument
signatur.xml => idsignatur
COO_2026_100_2_dokument.xml => idCOO_2026_100_2
COO_2026_100_2_dokument.rtf => idCOO_2026_100_2
COO_2026_100_2_signatur.xml => idCOO_2026_100_2
COO_2026_100_3_dokument.xml => idCOO_2026_100_3
```

Comment: `*signatur.*` and `*dokument.*` belong together in the same group, so they must get the same id. Otherwise fine.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found one solution. By changing the pattern to

```
my ($match) = ($_ =~ /(.*?)(?:_?(?:dokument|signatur))?(?:\..*)/);
```

the leading _ will be ignored in the id and everything is fine.

I'm still interested in a solution using lookahead, if this is possible. I never quite understood the idea.

Comment: There's no reason for a lookahead here.  It's a tool like any other, and it's good that you want to learn it.  However, one doesn't use a screwdriver to put in a nail.

Comment: I know, but here I understand exactly what the problem is, and seeing the solution I'll probably understand the lookahead easier. I was thinking along "if this dokument|signatur is preceded by an _, remove that as well"...so actually it's more of a look-behind?!.

Comment: But you're right, of course. A solution is a solution. Why bother.

Comment: @Miller I agree that a lookahead isn't the most efficient way to do it, but it sounded to me like he didn't just want to solve this particular problem, he wanted to take the opportunity to also understand how to use lookahead assertions.

Comment: BTW, I wouldn't say it's like using a screwdriver to put in a nail, i.e. a tool that's *not suited* for the job. It's more like using a palate jack to move a box that can easily fit on a dolly: it's a tool that's suited for the job but is more powerful and less efficient than what you need. But you might do it anyway if you expect that you'll need to move larger boxes in the future and want to practice using a palate jack.

Comment: @AdiInbar Respect.  Yes, it can be useful to practice different approaches to the same problem.  I did the same using 5 different solutions to this problem: [how to count the number of occurences of successful matches based on a condition on their absolute positions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25679399/1733163).  However, continuing the analogy, if someone hasn't mastered a hammer yet, they might want to wait before using a jackhammer.  :)

Comment: I'm not sure how well the analogy carries...misusing a jackhammer can cause destruction and injury, whereas the only dangers of misusing zero-width assertions are that the regex won't work or won't be as efficient, so it's not so important to be "ready" to use them. But I agree it's a fair point to warn that they should be used only when you *need* them, not just any time you *can*. It's advice I've often given myself: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18808873/1248365, http://stackoverflow.com/a/21392213/1248365 No harm in learning them right away, but be aware that they have their time and place.

Comment: I read your answer to the linked question, you had some good points in the comments.  Aye, I'm not worried about injury, as much as it is increasing the number of ways that someone can make a mistake when they haven't demonstrated mastery of the simpler (and sufficient) tools already at their disposal.  I tend to believe that it's an important paradigm to break down a problem into simpler steps if one can.  That's why my answer demonstrated a single regex, but I actually recommended doing it via steps with s///.  Easier to comprehend and less risk of bugs for both beginner and expert.

Comment: @Miller: I appreciate your concern for my safety :), however I do feel quite comfortable with regexes in general. And why you think I haven't demonstrated mastery of the screwdriver eludes me a bit, since I found a working solution, whereas yours is not quite correct, as I pointed out in a comment. Still, thanks for your time and effort.